# How to write this matlab code without a for loop

Tags: matlab

I have the following matlab code:

```
    messages_llr_matrix = sparse(ROW_NUM, COL_NUM);
    for index = 1 : length(II)
        messages_llr_matrix(II(index), JJ(index)) = ...
        code_word_aprior_prob(JJ(index));
    end
```

This code takes a vector and copies it, to a sparse matrix rows if the element in the matrix is not zero.

matlab tells me not to use indexing in the previous matlab code, because it makes it very slow.
I want to build the `messages_llr_matrix` matrix in the following manner:

```
messages_llr_matrix = sparse(II,JJ,code_word_aprior_prob,ROW_NUM,COL_NUM);
```

This is not a solution that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that in your latter code `II(ind)`, `JJ(ind)` and `code_word_aprior_prob(ind)` should go together, but in your convention you need `code_word_aprior_prob(JJ(ind))`.

Try calling

```
messages_llr_matrix = sparse(II,JJ,code_word_aprior_prob(JJ),ROW_NUM,COL_NUM);
```

Comment: `sparse` is **designed** to take in vectors.  Actually try and use the code before commenting.  Doing `code_word_aprior_prob(JJ)` will simply index into the vector to produce **another vector**.

Comment: @yaron, if it wasn't for my quick wits, sharp eyes and formidable modesty, it would've been really hard to debug your problem. If you ask a question next time, make sure to 1. specify what your goal is, 2. specify what you get instead, 3. quote any error messages, if applicable, 4. try out what solutions others suggest.